Nmap Database Scanning? How to do that?
I am unable to find a solution for it. Can anyone please tell me the process and steps involved in it? enter image description here
I searched the Nmap scripts and commands and I didn't get the clear information from the web. Can anyone tell me what the process is?

Well firstly, make sure you have permission to do this.
nmap -A <ipaddr>
Look for common database services, you can google the ports, example MySQL uses 3306.
You can do version detection using this
nmap -sV -p <portno> <ipaddr>
Then you can look for specific vulnerabilities using this nmap --script mysql-vuln-cvenoxxx <ipaddr>
You need to find the scripts yourself in the nmap docs. https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/mysql-databases.html
Good luck.
